# Cannot turn on Mac Webcam through OpenCV python

Tags: python, computer-vision, pycharm, opencv

I am new to opencv and trying to access my Macbook's built-in camera through OpenCV python but it gives an error.

```
import cv2

frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10,150)

while True:
   success, img = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow("Result", img)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hasanaktas/PycharmProjects/OpencvPython/project3.py", line 12, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Result", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

already tried changing VideoCapture(0) to VideoCapture(1) and adding the following code but still didn't help. Btw using PyCharm

```
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is `cap.set(10,150)`? Try to avoid ugly constants like that and use the parameter names defined for you.

Comment: How are you calling it?  I was told at work that Apple recently blocked anything that was not signed by an `Apple Developer` from accessing any of the peripherals.  This gave us problems because it would not let Audacity access the mic.  We had to build a shell script wrapper around it.  Bash was signed so the bash script that called audacity was allowed to access the mic.

Comment: I don't recommend using the opencv video streaming functions with Apple devices; I've never gotten them to work. Instead, maybe consider streaming from an AVCaptureSession and sending the individual frames to your function. After all, a video is merely a series of individual images. Try using the UIImageToMat function (you may have to use the c++ library).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on my Mac. I simply replaced

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

with

```
cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

There are two suggestions I would like to mention.

**#1:** Enable your terminal or PyCharm to reach the camera.

---

- Go to `System Preferences`-> `Security and Privacy` -> `Camera` and add PyCharm to the list.

  - [image]

**#2** Instead of `while True` use `while cap.isOpened()`, so you can know that `PyCharm` or `terminal` can access your camera.

- ```py
  import cv2

  frameWidth = 640
  frameHeight = 480
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  cap.set(3, frameWidth)
  cap.set(4, frameHeight)
  cap.set(10,150)

  while cap.isOpened():
      success, img = cap.read()
      if success:
          cv2.imshow("Result", img)
          if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
              break
  ```

Comment: what if it's not on the list?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did not find any solution. By trial and error, I found that my `OpenCV` version is corrupted. As a result, I deleted it and install a new fresh one. You can use one of these two options:
**1. Terminal**
run `brew uninstall opencv3` to uninstall `opencv`
then install it using `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv` command.

**2. Anaconda**
Actually, I used this method for my own problem.

1. open anaconda
2. go to the environment section and select your environment as follow:
   [image]
   then click on installed and search for `opencv`:
   [image]
   select `opencv` package and uninstall it. then try to re-install `opencv` by selecting not installed and searching for `opencv`. be careful to install the correct version.
   [image]

Answer (score -2):

Try to increase frame width/height, for example use:

frameWidth = 1048
frameHeight = 1028